# How to set point "Use classpath of module" not checked by default in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

To run applications, I constantly need to uncheck "Use classpath on modules". Maybe someone knows a way to make it unchecked by default?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run | Edit Configurations` and click the `Edit configuration templates...` link in the left bottom. Uncheck `Use classpath on modules` there, and it will be unchecked by default when you create a new Run configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it. It'll take some time.